# how to create Android map v2 using MapView class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

how to create android map v2 using mapview class, how to develop it, i have developed using MapFragment and SupportedMapFragment but i need use MapView class for creating gooogle map.

please help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

SomeFragment.java:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);
// Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
mapView = (MapView) v.findViewBy(R.id.mapview);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
map = mapView.getMap();
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

// Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
try {
MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
// Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
mapView.onResume();
super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
mapView.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

SomeManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>
<permission
android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="your_key"/>
<activity
android:name=".HomeActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

some_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

May it helps you...

For more info:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Google Map version 2 , you can not use MAPView class now, because it is deprecated now. You can refer this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Example Code : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

All the Best..
Hope this help..

Comment: i have implemented it working fine but i need to use Mapview class for createing Google map

Comment: Maps v2 contains a MapView class, and it's not deprecated.